# jsColor can't find hs.png in ASP.Net MVC Azure App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, jscolor

i've implemented the [JSColor Plugin](http://jscolor.com/) into my ASP.Net Site. Everything works fine except the background image hs.png is not showing up. I put the jscolor.js, hs.png and hv.png to the Scripts\JSColor - Folder. I'm using Scriptbundling for all of my Javascript files.

If run the application on my machine (in release or debug mode) the plugin finds all files in the scirpts/jscolor - folder. When I publish the application to Azure, the console logs:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://....azurewebsites.net/Employee/jscolor/cross.gif`

The plugin looks for the files in the wrong folder, according to the selected route.

Comment: I don't think this is to do with Azure. I get the same issue in a non Azure MVC site when running the site through Visual Studio. It is looking for `http://localhost:50155/Content/Content/jscolor/cross.gif` - for some reason the Content folder is stated twice. I installed using NuGet so all files should be in the correct directories.

Comment: Are they referred to, by explicit path or via wildcard, in your Bundle.cs file? The fact that the files load locally might be because of how VS handles relative files when debugging on the fly (aka the files `happen` to be there). But unless they aren't explicitly included via a call in Bundle you can't assume that they will be available in production